# Can I have gradients with alpha channel in IE8 and most other browsers

Tags: html, css

I am using the `following code`:

```
-moz-linear-gradient(top , rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,0));
```

But I would like to implement a similar `gradient` in the `other browsers. My problem is that I don't know if I can use the alpha channel and I don't want to use images I would just like to do it with code only.

Can someone tell me if it's possible.

Hope you can help

Answer (score 0):

you'd have to create partially transparent pngs or look at using the filters MS provide (though they are much maligned I should add...)

['cross' browser gradients](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/15/css-gradients-for-all-web-browsers-without-using-images/)

Personally these are decoration facets that IMO don't destroy the exerpince of a site - to that end when possible I wouldn't even bother - IE9 will take up significant market share within 12 months and all the work you are about to do won't be needed anymore

Comment: IE8 will be the new 6 by then :)

Comment: Indeed - lol. in the grand scheme of things though if ie8< can't render a partially transparent background gradient is it really going to stop a site being enjoyed? I think not. Those who only use ie8< won't expect anything and those who are wise will get a lovely  gradient in a bleeding edge design. who is getting hurt here?

Comment: That's what the beauty of an .htc patch is: Throw it away when you don't need it. Think about this 3 way convo I had with my boss, and a new client looking at a prototype: BOSS: "Looks nice with those gradients right?" CLIENT (on IE):"Erm what gradients?" - I felt like an idiot having to explain it, then had to make sure it worked in IE...

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/), it handles this fairly well for IE, although it requires `position` to be set, and can break on elements that get hidden, and there's a short delay when rendering the gradient...

Webkit has a different approach to linear-gradient, you can see an example on the link.